# How to use RaspberryPi to program windows form or web application in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, raspberry-pi

Has anyone worked with RaspberryPI to develop windows app using Visual Studio? If so i need some help around, thanks.

Comment: Raspberry PI is an OS created for specific purpose, to run on a Raspberry PI computer which in turn have a very specific purpose. So creating a program on Raspberry PI does not justify it's usage. Can you explain what is your requirement that asks you to create a WindowsForms or MVC application on raspberry PI.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/what-%20is-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @Chetan i need to create a GUI using VS through RaspberryPI, hope make sense

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Raspberries are not restricted to run what was formerly known as Raspbian. You _can_ run a special version of Windows 10 on it, amongst other options. And I'd also object to _"which in turn have a very specific purpose"_. Raspberries can and are utilized in a broad variety of applications. The only restriction is that the application must be able to work with the Pi's low resources.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the explanation. I got the point. I still wonder if Raspberry PI OS is a good platform to do development? I prefer to do development on regular linux or Window machine and deploy my application on the device running on Raspberry PI.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Me, too. But if it is the explicit requirement to develop on it ... so be it. I don't see how you would install Visual Studio on a Linux-based OS, though. Maybe the required framework and tools and VS Code... Also Winforms/WPF won't work (afaik) on Linux, but the question is tagged asp.net-mvc, so I guess it shall be a "Web-GUI", OP?

Comment: Any ideas at least so can start doing the work its doable

Comment: @mailertestmail You need to install .NET Core SDK, ASP.NET Core SDK, VS Code on Raspberry PI. This will get you started with developing MVC application. As Fildor mentioned above, WindowsForms/WPF application development on Linux is not available. You can refer to various articles on Google about ASP.NET Core development on Linux. [here](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/03/20/net-core-linux/), [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781785886751/1/ch01lvl1sec15/creating-an-asp-net-core-mvc-application-on-linux)

Comment: @Chetan thanks mate, i have an idea now. Follow the instruction from the link and take from there. AT least have got something to work on.